# Fill pygame font with custom pattern

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently working on a (first) project in Python/Pygame and I'm trying to display text with a pattern overlay. The pattern consists vertical lines (1 pixel width), 2 alternating colors .

I'm creating this pattern using pygame.draw.line(), and I can create rectangles with a custom function I created. But now I want this pattern on my font.

I'm new to Python and am wondering: is there a way to create some sort of mask so that the pattern will appear on the font characters only, not outside of them? I've searched the web for some time but cannot find anything.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the different blend modes to get the effect you desire.

Here's a simple example (where `t.bmp` is the image with your pattern, but of course you can just use any other surface):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((490, 160))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 150)
pattern = pygame.image.load('t.bmp').convert()
text = font.render('FooBar', True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))

pattern.blit(text, (0, 0), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_MULT)

screen.blit(pattern, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip();
while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT):
        break
```

**Result:**

[image]